# DCount Type Mismatch Error VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to use DCount to see if records exist in a table before inserting the data into the database but I keep getting a type mismatch error on "Customer Number" and have no idea why. The code is below:

```
Public Sub ExportData()
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dbPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\PRID.mdb"
dbWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
dbWs = Application.ActiveSheet.Name
scn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
dsh = "[" & Application.ActiveSheet.Name & "$]"
cn.Open scn

ssql = "INSERT INTO [Investment Data] ([Customer Number])"
ssql = ssql & "SELECT  [Customer Number] FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & dsh

If Application.WorksheetFunction.DCount("Customer Number", "Investment Data", "[Customer Number]=" & Range("A2")) > 0 Then
    MsgBox ("A similar entry has been detected within the PRID database, please make sure that this is a new entry before you continue.")
Else
    MsgBox ("Entry has been entered into the database.")
    cn.Execute ssql
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: The first parameter should be your "field name", so does it need to be "[Customer Number]"?  Also `"Customer Number=" & Range("A2")` should probably be `"[Customer Number]=" & Range("A2")` or, maybe, `"[Customer Number]='" & Range("A2") & "'"` (Not an expert on this aspect of VBA, so I am guessing.)  Also, you have a typo in `before you contiue`.  (But I doubt if that is causing any issues! ;) )

Comment: What exactly are you trying to use DCount *on*?  Is the data already in Excel? It would be a lot easier to see what is going on if you posted the rest of the code.

Comment: Also (and only tangentially related to your question), enforcing database unique constraints on the client side is a losing battle.  The real solution would be to normalize and configure the DB to reject duplicate records - then just check for the INSERT error on the client side.

Comment: @Comintern I'm trying to use the DCount on a table in an Access Database, basically the excel spreadsheet will export the record to the Access Database if their isn't already an existing record in the DB. Range("A2") is a field in excel spreadsheet to see if record already exists in Access DB

Comment: @Comintern updated to include all the code shortened the ssql because it would be over 100 fields

Comment: The syntax for the Excel DCOUNT function is `DCOUNT(database, field, criteria)` so you probably need `DCount("[Investment Data]", "[Customer Number]", "[Customer Number]="& Range("A2"))`

Comment: @YowE3K I tried changing it up but still the same error, and if I dont include Application.WorksheetFunction before the DCount I get a Sub or Function not defined error isntead.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't intending that you should try it without the "Application.WorksheetFunction" part - it's definitely needed.  That was just me being lazy while typing the comment.

Comment: It appears that Excel requires the criteria to be formed by having the "Customer Number" and the "=A2" in a 2-cell vertical range.

Answer (score 0):

### This should resolve your problem

You can add a WHERE clause to your query that will skip the [Customer Number] that already exists in the [Investment Data] table.

```
ssql = ssql & _
 " WHERE [Customer Number] NOT IN(SELECT [Customer Number] FROM [Investment Data]);)"
```

You can then use `Connection.Execute` to return the number of records added.

```
Results = cN.Execute(ssql)

MsgBox Results & " Records were added " & (allRecordsCount - Results) & "Records Were Skipped"
```

---

If you want to alert the user before you insert the records you'll need two queries.

```
ssql = ssql & "SELECT [Customer Number] FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & dsh & _
   ssql & " WHERE [Customer Number] IN(SELECT [Customer Number] FROM [Investment Data]);)"


Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set rs = cN.Execute(ssql)


If Not rs.BOF AND  Not rs.EOF Then
    msg = msg & vbCrLf & rs.Fields("Customer Number").Value
    rs.MoveNext
End If

If msg <> "" Then

    MsgBox "These Records Are Duplicates" & vbCrLf & msg
    Exit Sub
End If
```

### This should answer your question

You are getting the "DCount Type Mismatch Error VBA" because you are trying to query an external Access Database using the Excel WorksheetFunction DCount.

### Test Queries

```
Public Sub TestQueries()
    Set cN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    dbPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path & "\PRID.mdb"
    'dbPath = "C:\Users\best buy\Downloads\stackoverfow\Sample Data File\test.mdb"
    dbWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    dbWs = Application.ActiveSheet.Name
    scn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
    dsh = "[" & Application.ActiveSheet.Name & "$]"
    cN.Open scn

    ssql = ssql & "SELECT [Customer Number] FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" & dbWb & "]." & dsh

    Set rs = cN.Execute(ssql)

    Do While Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & rs.FIelds(0).Value
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    MsgBox msg, vbInformation, "Results Query Without Where Clause"

    ssql = ssql & _
 " WHERE [Customer Number] IN(SELECT CDbl([Customer Number]) FROM [Investment Data])"

    msg = ""

    Set rs = cN.Execute(ssql)

    Do While Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & rs.FIelds(0).Value
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    MsgBox msg, vbInformation, "Results Query With Where Clause"


End Sub
```

Comment: I need to alert the user that their is a similar entry already in the DB so they can make appropriate changes. I'm just not sure how this would allow it. Also only 1 row of data will be exported at a time not multiple.

Comment: I'm getting a data type mismatch in criteria expression error when it tries to run the 'Set rs = cN.Execute(ssql)' line.

Comment: If i remove the `WHERE` and `IN` clause, I get another error "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed" on the `If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then` condition

Comment: I get the operations not allowed error at the `Do While` Loop, so I commented out my `INSERT INTO` clause and it returned a result (The Customer Number). It then gets a data type mismatch on the second `Set rs = cN.Execute(ssql)`

Comment: Yes, using latest one

Comment: Is [Customer Number]  a text field in the database?

Comment: I just updated my answer casting the [Customer Number]  into a number.  I believe that it will work now.

Comment: I tried the revised version and it works with the `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses, but as soon as I bring the `INSERT INTO` back into the SUB I get a _Operation is not allowed when the object is close_ error.